# How To Loop Through A List Of Indicators?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have an array of icons (with material ui) and I want to display them using a map loop but it's not working. Here's the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { IconButton } from "@mui/material";
import {
  Computer,
  Inventory,
  Medication,
  Gavel,
  MilitaryTech,
  ContentCut,
  SportsMma,
  LocalDining,
  Synagogue,
  Diversity1,
  Security,
  Event,
} from "@mui/icons-material";

export function MadorimIcons() {
  const icons = [
    <Computer />,
    <Inventory />,
    <Medication />,
    <Gavel />,
    <MilitaryTech />,
    <ContentCut />,
    <SportsMma />,
    <LocalDining />,
    <Synagogue />,
    <Diversity1 />,
    <Security />,
    <Event />,
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <div
        width={100}
        display="flex"
        position="absolute"
        alignItems="center"
        whiteSpace="normal"
        gap={5}
        sx={{ whiteSpace: "normal" }}
      >
        {icons.map((icon) => (
          <IconButton color="primary">
            <icon key={icon.id} sx={{ fontSize: "15vw" }} />
          </IconButton>
        ))}
  );
}
```

It seems JS is reading `icon` as a name of an indicator and not as a variable, but if I put it in `{icon}` I get an error